# Error 404:The requested resource [/] is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

[Problem image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjhUU.png)

I am not understanding why I am getting this error .

Controller class:

```
    package com.emusicstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class homeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Here is the location of my home.jsp
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PFR4.png)

Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

use /* in your url-pattern so that DispatcherServlet will now intercept all requests with pattern /* for example /home

Comment: Hey I tried doing it but I am still getting the same error. Please let me know if there is an alternative .Much appreciate your time.